# simple false position with matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do a simple [False Position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method) code following my teachers model but can't get it to actually work.  Not sure if my if-else is correct or what as it only says `Method Failed` but I know there should be an answer of `P=3.0571` and `i=16`. Totally new to programming and matlab so any help would be greatly valued. Thanks

```
%False Position
%(x^2-4x+4-lnx=0 for 2<=x<=4)

p0=2; p1=4; TOL=10^-6; N=100;

q0=p0^2-4*p0+4-log(p0);
q1=p1^2-4*p1+4-log(p1);

i=2;
while i<=N
    p=p1-q1*(p1-p0)/(q1-q0);

    if abs(p-p1)<TOL
        disp('False Position')
        p
        i
        break
    end



    i=i+1;
    q=p^2-4*p+4-log(p);

    if q*q1<0
        p0=p1;
        q0=q1;
    else
        p1=p;
        q1=q;
    end
end

   if i>=N disp('Method Failed')
   end
```

Comment: (for future readers) Aside from the corrections and hints in the answer of Bas Swinckels, the condition for the break should include both sides of the interval. The shrinking of the interval length to zero mostly never happens in plain vanilla regula falsi or false position. So use `if abs(p-p0)<TOL | abs(p-p1)<TOL`. One may also play with the reduction of the opposite function value, i.e., additionally to `p0=p; q0=q` also do `p1*=0.95`. Or use the Illinois variant of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really familiar with the false position method, but it seems you are trying to find the zero of some function by shrinking some interval at every step by setting either the left or right edge to some intermediate value based on some condition. I think there is a bug in your `if`: in case `q*q1<0`, you set the left edge to the same values as the right edge. You probably need to change it to:

```
if q*q1<0
    p0=p;q0=q;
else
    p1=p;q1=q;
end
```

Note that I only changed `p1` to `p` and `q1` to `q`.

For the rest your code looks OK, but I would suggest some small changes to make it more readable: change all `p` and `q` to `x` and `y`, and maybe define your function as a function handle (type `help function_handle`). Right now, you are defining your function in 3 different places. If you want to change your function in the future, you would have to make the exact same change in all those places, or you would have a bug. It is better to [not repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself) and define your function only once as `fun = @(x) x^2-4*x+4-log(x);`, and then later use it as `y0 = fun(x0)` and `y1 = fun(x1)` etc.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helps me get the P, but the i isn't the same 16 that I'm supposed to be getting, mine is 39).  I will also try your function handle for my next assignment. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that the answer is correct, but I don't know why the number of iterations is different. Double-check your formulas and then ask your teacher, maybe he used a slightly different algorithm or tolerance. Please accept the answer if you are happy.

Comment: Sorry this is the fist time using this site.  Did I accept the answer?